# Remove one object from an array and return the result

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have some objects in an array:

```
var names = [
    { id:"101", name:"eric" },
    { id:"202", name:"john" },
    { id:"303", name:"zack" },
    { id:"404", name:"ron" }
];
```

I want to remove one of the objects. I have only one piece data to check the object array against, which is the `id = 202`. Finally, I want to return the adjusted array, like this:

```
[
    { id:"101", name:"eric" },
    { id:"303", name:"zack" },
    { id:"404", name:"ron" }
];
```

Comment: That is not JSON. That is a JavaScript array literal.

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the use of [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var res = names.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.id !== "202";
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

In javascript you can use either Array.filter or Array.reject to return an array of objects that you want. Below I have demonstrated how to achieve this using filter.

```
names.filter(function(eachObject){ return eachObject.id !== '202';})
```

Array.filter is a native function that will take an existing array and return a new array with the filtered values. It does this by iterating over each item in the array and running a predicate/truth function on every single item. If an item passes the truth test it is pushed into the new array. Once the iterating is complete, filter will return a brand new array with only the values that pass the test.

In the example above the predicate function is an anonymous function that we passed into filter. You can also pass in a function that has been previously declared like so.

```
function idNotTwoZeroTwo(eachObject){ return eachObject.id !== '202'};
names.filter(idNotTwoZeroTwo) // gives you same result
```

Also, you are not actually representing proper JSON in your example. If you have time go through a quick tutorial at http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp to brush up.

One more thing. If in the future you want to check to see if something is in proper JSON just go to http://jsonlint.com/ and copy your code in. It will tell you wether or not your code is correct JSON.  It will even tell you exactly what is wrong.

This is my first answer so Im sorry if I didn't answer your question fully. Hope it helps.!

Answer (score 0):

Hi u can use underscore js very simple

```
var names = [
    { id:"101", name:"eric" },
    { id:"202", name:"john" },
    { id:"303", name:"zack" },
    { id:"404", name:"ron" }
];

console.log(_.reject(names, function(num){ return num.id == "202"; }))
```

include the library underscore

Comment: There is no need to use a library!

Comment: Underscore is a JavaScript library that provides a whole mess of useful functional programming helpers without extending any built-in objects, Underscore provides over 100 functions. in future if he wants to write many operations better to use this , its  my suggestion

Comment: It is better to learn and understand plain JavaScript first. Then, if it is usefull, one can look into a helpfull library for special cases.